# Customize ASP.NET Chart DataPoint Based On Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts, mschart

I'm unable to change the color for each datapoint respectively.

Condition is if number <= 10, color will be red. if number > 10, color will be green.

Codes (I did try using a foreach loop then a for loop, but to no avail..)
Please just take a look at //Available :

```
        ChartClass.Series.Clear();

        BedsBLL get = new BedsBLL();

        int A1Available = get.countAvailA1();
        int A1Alloted = get.countUnavailA1();
        int B1Available = get.countAvailB1();
        int B1Alloted = get.countUnavailB1();
        int B2Available = get.countAvailB2();
        int B2Alloted = get.countUnavailB2();
        int C1Available = get.countAvailC1();
        int C1Alloted = get.countUnavailC1();

        //Available
        Series seriesAvail = ChartClass.Series.Add("SeriesAvailable");
        seriesAvail.Color = Color.ForestGreen;
        seriesAvail.LegendText = "Available Number of Beds";

        String[] classArrAvail = { "A1", "B1", "B2", "C1" };
        int[] countAvailable = { A1Available, B1Available, B2Available, C1Available };

        ChartClass.Series["SeriesAvailable"].Points.DataBindXY(classArrAvail, countAvailable);

        ChartClass.Series["SeriesAvailable"].YValuesPerPoint = 2;

        foreach (DataPoint pt in ChartClass.Series["SeriesAvailable"].Points)
        {
            if (pt.XValue <= 10)
            {
                pt.Color = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (pt.XValue > 10)
            {
                pt.Color = Color.ForestGreen;
            }

            /*for (int i = 0; i < countAvailable.Length; i++)
            {
                if (countAvailable[i] <= 10)
                {
                    pt.Color = Color.Red;
                }
                else if (countAvailable[i] > 10)
                {
                    pt.Color = Color.ForestGreen;
                }
            }*/
        }

        //Alloted
        Series seriesAlloted = ChartClass.Series.Add("SeriesAlloted");
        seriesAlloted.Color = Color.Gray;
        seriesAlloted.LegendText = "Alloted Number of Beds";

        String[] classArrAlloted = { "A1", "B1", "B2", "C1" };
        int[] countAlloted = { A1Alloted, B1Alloted, B2Alloted, C1Alloted };

        ChartClass.Series["SeriesAlloted"].Points.DataBindXY(classArrAlloted, countAlloted);
```

[image]

Designer:

```
                <asp:Chart ID="ChartClass" runat="server" Height="350px" Width="380px"> 
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="SeriesAvailable" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" LabelAngle="-90" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt" Legend="LegendClass" ChartArea="ChartAreaClass" ChartType="StackedColumn">
                        <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="false" />
                    </asp:Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="SeriesAlloted" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" LabelAngle="-90" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt" Legend="LegendClass" ChartArea="ChartAreaClass" ChartType="StackedColumn">
                        <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="false"/>
                    </asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartAreaClass">
                        <AxisX Title="Class">
                            <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
                        </AxisX>
                        <AxisY Title="Number of Beds">
                            <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
                        </AxisY>
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
                <Legends>
                    <asp:Legend Docking="Bottom" Name="LegendClass"></asp:Legend>
                </Legends>
                <Titles>
                    <asp:Title Name="TitleChart" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 15pt, style=Bold" Text="Beds Statistics Summary (Class)" Alignment="TopCenter"></asp:Title>
                </Titles>
                </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: I answered a similar question, take a look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807084/how-to-customize-asp-net-chart-databound-to-sqldatasource/38811378#38811378).

Comment: But why do i need a random? Mine is based on a condition then changing the color of that datapoint that met that condition.. Sorry i'm kind of lost.. I have only done 2 charts so far since i started asp.net.. @jstreet

Comment: You don't need a random. You just need to handle the `PreRender` event. But now i see you're explicitly adding your data points (not from database, like in my sample) so, maybe you don't need even that.... Use the debugger to make sure the loop changing the color is working properly.

Comment: My data points is actually from a database with Select Count statement.. But i don't think it affects. And how can i do that..? @jstreet

Comment: i actually tried using this if else statement since i'm playing around with specifically the XValues.. Will edit the question and add the codes in @jstreet It actually changes all the data points to red..

Comment: In your loop, you should be comparing the value of `pt` with your color threshold, but you're not doing that...

Comment: sorry.. i don't get what is color threshold.. i actually got the foreach loop from this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519727/how-to-add-different-color-of-column-in-chart-control-in-asp-net)

Comment: Take a look at my post below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop for setting the color is incorrect. Here's how you should do it:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] classArrAvail = { "A1", "B1", "B2", "C1" };
        int[] countAvailable = { 20, 5, 10, 15 };

        Chart1.Series["SeriesAvailable"].Points.DataBindXY(classArrAvail, countAvailable);

        foreach (DataPoint pt in Chart1.Series["SeriesAvailable"].Points)
        {
            if (pt.YValues[0] <= 10)
                pt.Color = Color.Red;
            else pt.Color = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** Adding ASPX for column labels:

```
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="600px">
        <series>
            <asp:Series Name="SeriesAvailable" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" LabelAngle="-90">
                <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="False" />
            </asp:Series>
        </series>
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                <AxisX>
                    <MajorGrid Enabled="False" />
                </AxisX>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

[image]

Comment: what if i'm using ["SeriesAvailable"] for the if else? and also.. Chart1.Series["SeriesAvailable"].Points.DataBindXY(classArrAvail, countAvailable); Thank you..

Comment: I used [0] instead.. Could you correct me if i'm wrong. 0 represents the first Series you added in your designer in your Chart. 1 represents the second series you added.. So on and so forth. @jstreet

Comment: You can just keep your series name. I am using `[0]` just because i did not name my series in my example.

Comment: It gives me an error when i use -> pt.YValues["SeriesAvailable"]. Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'. @jstreet

Comment: Basically you have to replace `pt.XValue` in your code with `pt.YValues[0]` as i did in my sample.

Comment: Ok, for the `YValue` you must use `YValues[0]`.

Comment: the 0 represents the first series created for chart?

Comment: No, `YValues` is an array of doubles. In a column chart, you just need `YValues[0]` but in other chart types you may need YValues[1], YValues[2], etc. This refers to the data point only, not the series. Don't mix those two...:O)

Comment: I'm going to update my code to use your series name, so it doesn't confuse you. And you're very welcome !

Comment: sorry last query.. for your link that you shared from your answer to the question. may i ask how do i show the numbers above the bars? i added all codes from the designer from the link you shared into mine, but it doesn't work.. is it because my chart isn't databounded to a datasource?

Comment: No, the fact that is data bound does not count. It should work the same if you add all that is needed from that ASPX.

Comment: okay i will try to manage. and comment back here. thanks jstreet!

Comment: is it possible to add another legend to tell users why the color red of the bar? without having to have another series.

Comment: The standard legend is one color per series. You would need a custom legend for that.

Comment: added exactly what you added.. weird it doesn't show up. i will add the codes into my question.. thanks @jstreet

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason but you should use chart type `Column`, not `StackedColumn`.

Comment: It didn't work because in my codes at the top i added Chart.Series.Clear(); I coded the things needed for the label to appear at the backend. It works now. Thank you so much once again! @jstreet

Comment: Congrats buddy, glad to help.